# Condense largely(Unpractical) loop based VBA code; nested For...Next loops

Tags: vba, loops, excel, for-loop

Hello everyone alright let start by giving some brief background on my project then I will follow up with my specific issue and code.

Currently I am building a program to automate the process of filling a template. This template exceeds 60,000 rows of data quite often and I've built the large majority of it to work month to month by plugging in new data sheets and running it. Currently all of the work is based off of one data sheet which I import into excel manually. This data sheet does not contain all the data I need to populate the template so now I am beginning to bring in additional data to supplement this. The problem herein lies with data association. When I was originally pulling from one data sheet I didn't have to worry if the data I pulled for each row coincided with the other rows because it all came from the same sheet. Now I have to cross check data across two sheets to confirm it is pulling the correct information.

Now for what you need to know. I am trying to fill a column that will be referred to as Haircut, but before I do that I need to confirm that I am pulling the correct haircut number in correlation to a Trade ID which was already populated into the template in a previous line of code.

Using similar logic that I have been using throughout my entire project this is a snippet of code I have to perform this task.

```
    Dim anvil as Worksheet
    Dim ALLCs as worksheet
    Dim DS as worksheet
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''code above this line is irrelevant to answer this question
    ElseIf InStr(1, DS.Cells(x, 2), "Haircut") Then
    Anvil.Select
        For y = 1 To 80
            If Anvil.Cells(1, y) = "Haircut" Then
                For Z = 1 To 80
                    If Anvil.Cells(1, Z) = "Trade ID" Then
                        For t = 2 To 70000
                            For u = 16 To 70000
                                If Anvil.Cells(t, Z) = ALLCs.Cells(u, 34) Then
                                ALLCs.Cells(u, 27) = Anvil.Cells(t, y)
                                End If
                            Next
                        Next
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
```

This code coupled with my other code I assume will in theory work, but I can only imagine that it will take an unbelievable amount of time(this program already takes 7 and a half minutes to run). Any suggestions on how to rewrite this code with better functionality, following this general logic?

Any help is appreciated, whether you completely revamp the code, or if you offer suggestions on how to cut down loops. I am also looking for suggestions to speed up the code in general aside from screen updating and calculation suggestions.

Comment: I've provided an answer in terms of the code being reduced - however asking for general advice about speeding up code is a bit out of scope for SO. If you have a particular example then you could post that as a separate question or even submit your code to the Code Review site - hope that helps :)

Comment: WOW! there is potential for 31 trillion loops, I bet a filter could do what you are asking for, even setting ranges dynamically could help as well, as others have said, link us up to a sample workbook

Comment: As a CR regular (and among the top VBA reviewers on CR), I agree with @SOofWXLS, posting *your complete working code* over on [codereview.se] will certainly tremendously improve this code's performance, readability and maintainability.

Comment: I would be very interested in that. I am unsure of the legality as I work for a large company. I imagine there is some sort of intellectual property thing barring me from inputting my code. Also I imagine I would have to change some identifiers to preserve some sense of confidentiality.

Comment: That's why you make it a sample workbook with fake data not the actual workbook with real data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the logic correctly then you can replace all but one of the loops with a `.Find()` method like so:

```
'// Dimension range objects for use
Dim hdHaricut As Excel.Range
Dim hdTradeID As Excel.Range
Dim foundRng As Excel.Range

With Anvil
    With .Range("A1:A80") '// Range containing headers
        '// Find the cell within the above range that contains a certain string, if it exists set the Range variable to be that cell.
        Set hdHaircut = .Find(What:="Haircut", LookAt:=xlWhole)
        Set hdTradeID = .Find(What:="Trade ID", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    End With
    '// Only if BOTH of the above range objects were found, will the following block be executed.
    If Not hdHaricut Is Nothing And Not hdTradeID Is Nothing Then
        For t = 2 To 70000
            '// Using the .Column property of the hdTradeID range, we can see if the value of Cells(t, hdTradeColumn) exists 
            '// in the other sheet by using another .Find() method.
            Set foundRng = ALLCs.Range(ALLCs.Cells(16, 34), ALLCs.Cells(70000, 34)).Find(What:=.Cells(t, hdTradeID.Column).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            '// If it exists, then pass that value to another cell on the same row
            If Not foundRng Is Nothing Then ALLCs.Cells(foundRng.Row, 27).Value = .Cells(t, hdHaircut.Column).Value
            '// Clear the foundRng variable from memory to ensure it isn't mistaken for a match in the next iteration.
            Set foundRng = Nothing
        Next
    End If
End With
```

Comment: I never used to - however I work in an environment where report formats are forever changed to meet user requirements, and so `.Find()` quickly became my best friend for working with headers!

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the .find function therefore I am unsure if will work as intended. Let me do some research in conjunction with your answer and I'll get back to you. That foundRng variable looks greek to me atm.

Comment: After looking through it I think this solution will work well @SOofWXLS is it possible for you to elaborate on some of the sections of your code and explain their functionality?

Comment: @dom176 `.Find` returns a `Range` object if it succeeds - if it doesn't find anything, it returns a *null reference*, and in VBA that's `Nothing`. So `If Not foobar Is Nothing Then` will execute code when `foobar` has an actual object reference.

Comment: so if my assumptions are correct, after the .find step hdhaircut will be set to the entire range of the column that contains the header haircut and same for the hdTradeID variable. Even after reading through the foundrng variable declaration I still don't understand what is being applied. @Mat'sMug

Comment: I've added comments in the code to hopefully guide you along with @Mat'sMug comments

Comment: @SOofWXLS thank you I want to confirm that works before I accept the answer so allow me to attempt to implement the code first, before I accept the answer.